# Checking a hash table if a key exists, otherwise default to something that exists and return that value

Tags: javascript

I have the following function which works great, but I would like to make sure that if the supplied `zone` does not exist, that it uses `default` zone key.

```
module.exports = (zone, key) => {

  const zones = {
    default: require('./default'),
    northeast: require('./northeast'),
    centralCoast: require('./centralCoast')
  };

  return zones[zone][key];
}
```

Is there a cooler way to do this straight in the return statement?  Right now, I am just using a conditional check to check if I get anything but undefined and return that..

How can I check that the `zone` is one of the `zones` like `northeast, centralCoast`, etc but if someone passes `western` it would just return values for `default`

Comment: I don't fully understand your code, you're returning locales, but your object is declared as zones. and then, what is the key parameter??

Comment: sorry each of the these are just maps, so for example if you require this particular function, call it `example`, and execute like `example('northeast', 'shipping')['some-value']` then it will return that value.

Comment: I assume `locales` should be the same object as `zones`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple ternary operator to achieve conditional logic in the `return` statement. You can also use an arrow function to omit having to specify explicit `return`:

```
module.exports = (zone, key) => zones[zone]
  ? zones[zone][key]
  : zones.default[key];
```

I suggest to also move some of the static (non-changing code) outside of the function so it's not unnecessarily executed on each function call:

```
// move constants outside of the function because there's no need to recreate them on each function call
const zoneNames = ['default', 'northeast', 'centralCoast'];

// import the zones dynamically
// this way, adding new zones requires only adding a string to the array above
const zones = zoneNames.reduce((zones, zoneName) => {
  zones[zoneName] = require(zoneName);
  return zones;
}, {});

module.exports = (zone, key) => zones[zone]
  ? zones[zone][key]
  : zones.default[key];
```